# Python: Generate multiple Solid Color Images by importing a csv file with the RGB color values

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I want to Generate multiple Solid Color Images by importing a csv file with the RGB color values.
The solid color images size is 1080 x 1080 px.
I want all solid color images to be stored in a folder named purple. The folder locates in `C:\Users\vera\Desktop\purple`.  The csv file here located in `C:\Users\vera\Desktop\colorP.csv`

I am using google colaboratory and Jupyter Lite to run the code below:

```py
type from PIL import Image
import csv
import os

csv_path = r"‪C:\Users\vera\Desktop\colorP.csv"
output_dir = r"‪C:\Users\vera\Desktop\purple"

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

with open(csv_path, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) # skip header row
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        r, g, b = map(int, row)
        img = Image.new('RGB', (1080, 1080), (r, g, b))
        filename = f"solid_color_{i+1}.png"
        output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
        img.save(output_path)here
```

I ran the code
But it alway return an error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory: '\u202aC:\Users\vera\Desktop\colorP.csv'"

Answer (score 0):

Your path must be with double \ \

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to open the file, your editor is adding `/u202a`, which is the unicode control character for `LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING`. Your error shows that as well and therefore the path name becomes incorrect....

Update your open line to...

```
with open(csv_path.strip("‪u202a"), 'r') as file:
    ....
```

and it should work. Do print the file name to be sure that it is correct.